# Node sends data back multiple times everytime a user adds new data

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

First of all, I would like to  apologize for the horribly worded title; I have been trying to think of one for the past 20 minutes but I do not know a succinct way to describe the problem I am having. If anyone has a better suggestion, please let me know or edit the title if you are able to.

**Background**: In order to learn NodeJS, I am creating a chat server. When the user clicks the `createRoomBtn`,  an event is created containing the name of the room the user just created,   and sent to the `socket.js` module in `app.js`, app.js then appends the room to the array of rooms (these rooms are displayed as a list in the browser),  and creates a broadcast event to all users including the active user.

**Problem**: Let's say there is an empty list,  and user adds a new room, titled "NodeJS", this will display the room on the screen, and everything is fine and dandy. Now, if I was to add another room, Socket.io, for example, the browser renders the following result: `Socket.io, NodeJS, NodeJS`. If I was to add "Javascript", the result would be `Javascript, Socket.io, NodeJS, Socket.io, Node.JS`. Basically, the browser renders the list over and over again, and each time the list shrinks by one. I do not have the slightest idea of why this is happening. The weird thing is that if I press refresh, the browser renders the list correctly `Javascript, Socket.io, NodeJS`. What is going on?

**socket.js**:

```
module.exports = function(io, rooms) {
    var chatrooms = io.of('/roomlist').on('connection', function(socket) {  //io.of creates a namespace 
        console.log('Connection established on the server');
        socket.emit('roomupdate', JSON.stringify(rooms));   


        socket.on('newroom', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            rooms.push(data);
            socket.broadcast.emit('roomupdate', JSON.stringify(rooms)); 
            socket.emit('roomupdate', JSON.stringify(rooms));   

        })      
    })

    var messages = io.of('/messages').on('connection', function(socket) {   
        console.log('Connected to the chatroom!');

        socket.on('joinroom', function(data) {
            socket.username = data.user; 
            socket.userpic = data.userPic;
            socket.join(data.room);         
        })

        socket.on('newMessage', function(data) {

            socket.broadcast.to(data.room_number).emit('messagefeed', JSON.stringify(data));  
        })
    })
}
```

**chatrooms.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{title}}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/chatrooms.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> </script> 
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script> 
        <script>
        $(function() {
            var host = '{{config.host}}';       
            var socket = io.connect(host + '/roomlist');

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                console.log('connection established');      
            })  
            socket.on('roomupdate', function(data) {
                $('.roomlist').html('');

                var procData = JSON.parse(data); 

                for (var i = 0; i < procData.length; i++) { 
                    var str = '<a href="room/' + procData[i].room_number + '"><li>'
                    + procData[i].room_name + '<li></a>'; 
                    $('.roomlist').prepend(str);

                    console.log(str);

                }
            }) 

            $(document).on('click', '#createRoomBtn', function() {
                var room_name = $('#newRoomText').val();
                console.log(room_name);
                if (room_name != '') {
                    var room_number = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
                    socket.emit('newroom', {room_name: room_name, room_number: room_number});
                    $('#newRoomText').val('');                  
                }
            }) 
        }) 

        </script>
    </head>  

<body>

    <div class="cr-userbox">
        <img src="{{user.profilePic}}" class="userPic">
        <h3 class="username">{{user.fullName}}| <a href="/logout">Logout</a></h3>
    </div>


    <div class="cr-container">
        <h1> ChatRooms</h1>
        <div class="cr-newroom">
            <input type="text" id="newRoomText" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="submit" id="createRoomBtn" value=" Create Room">
        </div>

        <div class="cr-roomlist">
            <ul class="roomlist">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if more information/modules are required, and I will be happy to provide them.

**Update1**: As correctly suggested by alex-rokabilis, I have changed `$('.roomlist').html() = ''` to `$('.roomlist').html('')`, however, the problem continues to persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem or not but you're getting nested list eliments because you have two opening `<li>` tags in your socket.on ('roomupdate') function

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is how you render your rooms in the html part, not how socket.io sends the data.
You use `$('.roomlist').html='';` but this is not doing anything! `.html` is a function in jquery so the right thing to do is `$('.roomlist').html('');`.

So basically you didn't erase the previous rooms but instead you only add more duplicates. Also something i noticed that is not part of your question, in your nodejs code you use: `socket.broadcast.emit('roomupdate', JSON.stringify(rooms)); 
socket.emit('roomupdate', JSON.stringify(rooms));`

if you want to broadcast something to all connected clients there is a function for it and also there is no need to stringify your data, socketio do this internally for you! So you could use something like this:
`io.emit('roomupdate',rooms);`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the jquery error, but it does not solve the problem. Also, I am using an older version of socket, so your code does not work, but I will definitely be using your recommendation in my next project!